# GLMER and Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue

Tags: logistic, optimization, lme4-nlme, numerics

I'm working on a logistic regression analysis using the lme4 package and function glmer. I built the following model:

```
results<-glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled*Season1+MPHW_Scaled*Season1+HW_Scaled*Season1+YP_Scaled*Season1+AG_Scaled*Season1+Shrub_Scaled*Season1+(1|ID)+(1|Site),data=animals,family=binomial)
```

MP_Scaled, MPHW_Scaled, etc. are continuous variables and Season1 is a categorical variable. My approach is to understand whether the selection of certain habitat types differs across seasons A,B, and C.

I received the following output/message:

[image]

I've re-scaled the continuous variables by dividing each linear distance (m) by 100-m. I ran this same analysis in SAS and the model converged. Is there a way to change the convergence criteria in the glmer model? In SAS, my model is specified as the following:

```
PROC GLIMMIX DATA=STUDYAREA;
```

CLASS ID SITE SEASON1;
  MODEL R0A1 = MP_SCALED|SEASON1 MPHW_SCALED|SEASON1 HW_SCALED|SEASON1 YP_SCALED|SEASON1 AG_SCALED|SEASON1 SHRUB_SCALED|SEASON1 / DIST=BINOMIAL LINK=LOGIT SOLUTION ODDSRATIO;
  RANDOM ID / TYPE = VC;
  RANDOM SITE / TYPE = VC;
  NLOPTIONS GCONV=0;
RUN;

The NLOPTIONS GCONV=0 is used to continue the estimation until the max gradient is sufficiently small, which is done by setting the GCONV=0. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: This post is practically unreadable without formatting--the system is misinterpreting some of the special characters.  Please edit it and use the tools above the textbox to format code and error messages.

Comment: @whuber, does that work? Sorry for the issues in posting earlier. I can't seem to find an easy way to post my R code/output without issues in formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the convergence criteria, e.g.

```
     glmerControl(...,
        check.conv.grad = .makeCC("warning", tol = 1e-2))
```

or change the optimization parameters via the `optCtrl` argument, although this is a bit obscure for the `bobyqa` optimizer (`help("bobyqa",package="minqa")`).  Check `help("convergence",package="lme4")` for more information about convergence, among other things the fact that

> (2) the magnitude of the scaled gradient increases with sample size, so that warnings will occur even for apparently well-behaved fits with large data sets.

If you get similar answers from `lme4` and `PROC GLIMMIX` I would conclude that the warning is a false positive.